Meaning of calling SKNode.run multiple times
I am aware that SpriteKit supports compound actions that run in parallel, sequence, etc., and are added to an SKNode with via a single call to SKNode.run
What is however, the meaning of multiple, consecutive calls to SKNode.run on the same SKNode.  Say I have MyScene and inside of update I have something like the following:
class MyScene : SKScene {
  override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    ...
    node.run(action1)
    node.run(action2)
    ...
  }
}

What does that mean?

that action1 and action2 run simultaneously/in parallel?
that action1 runs to completion and then action2 does?
something else

Is that even defined behavior (I could not find anything in the docs)?
If it is 1. or 2. above, then are they equivalent to node.run(.group(...)) and node.run(.sequence(...)), respectively?  If yes, then does anyone know where is this documented?

Per the documentation of SKNode.run(_:):

The new action is processed the next time the scene’s animation loop is processed.

So all actions added using SKNode.run(_:) will start processing in the next animation loop, at the same time.

The SKNode.run(_:withKey:) method however "Adds an identifiable action to the list of actions executed by the node.".
This means the action can be retrieved later and if another action with the same key is already running, it is removed first.
